# Why the curve $x^2+y^2+y+1=0$ has only one point over $\mathbb{F}_{3^7}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, finite-fields, experimental-mathematics

According to both sagemath and Magma the curve $x^2+y^2+y+1=0$ has only one point over $\mathbb{F}_{3^7}$.

The projective closure has only one point too.

> Q1 What hypothesis are missing to not violate the [Hasse-Weil Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves)?

> Q2 Does this curve has only one point over $GF(3^{2n+1})$ for all $n$?

Magma [online](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/):

```
p:=3^7;
K<x,y>:=AffineSpace(GF(p),2);
C:=Curve(K,x^2+y^2+y+1);
pc:=ProjectiveClosure(C);
Genus(pc);
Points(pc);
IrreducibleComponents(pc);
```

Comment: $x^2+y^2+y+1=x^2+(y-1)^2$ doesn't define a smooth curve. Since $GF(3^{2n+1})$ doesn't contain a square root of $-1$, there will be no nontrivial points.

Comment: Also the curve is irreducible but not geometrically irreducible (you again need a square root of $-1$ to "see" the reducibility). So over $\operatorname{GF}(3^{2n+1})$ the number of irreducible components is $1$, whereas over $\operatorname{GF}(3^{2n})$ the number of irreducible components is $2$.

Comment: I want to record that I disagree with the downvoters: This is a basic point for those who know algebraic geometry over non-algebraically closed fields, but there is nothing wrong with asking the question. (Wojowu and RP_'s comments are, of course, completely correct.)

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks. If I set $u=(y-1)$ then the curve is homogeneous $x^2+u^2=0$. It is in projective space, but doesn't define curve. This is counter-intuitive for me, what is the intuition for it?

Comment: @RP_ Thanks. If I set $u=(y-1)$ then the curve is homogeneous $x^2+u^2=0$. It is in projective space, but doesn't define curve. This is counter-intuitive for me, what is the intuition for it?

Comment: A homogeneous equation in affine space defines a cone over the equation where one of the parameters is set to $1$. So this is a cone over the zero set of $x^2+1$. But a cone over a set of points equals a set of lines (in this case two), which intersect precisely at the apex of the cone. Moreover, in this case, the lines are defined over a field $k$ if and only if $k$ contains the zeros of $x^2+1$.

Comment: A homogeneous equation in two variables doesn't define a curve in projective space, but rather a 0-dimensional object.

Comment: @Wojowu Well, that depends on how you interpret the equation of course. But considered "on the nose", I would say the equation $x^2+u^2=0$ does indeed define a curve in affine $(x,u)$-space (although this depends on your precise definition of a curve, whether you require it to be smooth, geometrically integral, etc.).

Comment: @RP_ In their last comment joro has asked about the equation in the projective space, which I addressed. (you are of course otherwise right)

Comment: @Wojowu All right, then I misunderstood. One still needs to add the stipulation though that one is considering the equation $x^2+u^2=0$ on the $1$-dimensional projective line with homogeneous coordinates $x,u$. If one considers it in the $2$-dimensional projective plane, say with homogeneous coordinates $x,u,z$, then one still gets a curve (using my inclusive definition of curve, which does not require smoothness or geometric integralness).

Comment: Without further details, it is very hard to tell anything. I know very little about CASes, but I think you need to check for smoothness and geometric integralness, which Magma can probably do for you (projectivity is another requirement, but I'm assuming that you are considering projective curves). But I'd suggest asking another question (either here or on Math.SE).

Comment: Since the Hasse-Weil theorem is, well, a theorem, one way to check that it doesn't satisfy the assumptions of Hasse-Weil would be to check that it doesn't have any points over a large enough finite field. That would automatically imply it is not geometrically irreducible (since there is a version of Hasse-Weil valid also for singular curves). For geometric irreducibility, surely any CAS will be capable to check irreducibility of polynomials over the algebraic closure of a finite field.

Comment: @RP_ I posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389717/properties-of-pointless-projective-curves-over-finite-fields. As a bonus, Magma told me to submit a bug about pointless curve. If you see bugs in the question, please edit or let me know.