# Properties of pointless projective curves over finite fields?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, rational-points, mathematical-software

Probably not research level, feel free to downvote.

We got construction of bounded degree projective curves
with no points over finite fields. This construction generalizes to higher dimension.

One of the curves over $GF(5)$ triggered internal Magma error, suggesting reporting the bug.

Working over $GF(p)$, let $f(x),g(y)$ be polynomials with no roots.
Let $n>1$ be integer and $s$ element of $GF(p)$ which is not
$n$-th power. Let $F$ be the homogenization of $f(x)^n-s g(y)^n=0$.
Then $F$ has no projective points. To go to higher dimension
take $(h(z)f(x))^n-s g(y)^n=0$

> Q1 What properties these pointless curves have, e.g.
> do they have some extremal invariants too?

> Q2 Are there theoretical reasons to explain why Magma
> fails to compute the Zeta function of pointless curve
> in this [example online](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)

```
p:=5;
K<x,y>:=AffineSpace(GF(p),2);
C:=Curve(K,x^8 + 2*y^8 - x^7 + x^6 - y^6 + 2*x^5 + 2*y^5 - 2*x^4 + 2*y^3 + 2*x^2 + y^2 - x - y + 2);
pc:=ProjectiveClosure(C);
Genus(pc);
Points(pc);
IrreducibleComponents(pc);
ZetaFunction(pc);//report a bug
```

Comment: Are you aware that these curves are not geometrically irreducible?

Comment: @abx  Yes, I am aware of this property, but still looking for other properties of the curves.